# Dynamic default value for frontmatter variables

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm looking for a way to use the value of a frontmatter variable as the default for another one. For example, `current_page.data.altTitle` should evaluate to `"Home"` for the following frontmatter block.

```
---  
title: "Home"  
---
```

Whereas `current_page.data.altTitle` should evaluate to `"foo"` for this one:

```
---  
title: "Home"
altTitle: "foo"  
---
```

So this boils down to the following points:

- Can I dynamically set the value of current_page.data.altTitle
- If so, where should I do this? In a template? Or can I tell middleman to do this on building before creating the html pages?
- If not, what is an elegant workaround? My first approach would be to write a helper method which returns altTitle, unless it is not set, in which case it would return title. Any suggestions for a better/cleaner workaround?

edit:
I'm just using the following small helper now, but if there's a cleaner approach, I'd still be happy to know about it.
In `config.rb`:

```
helpers do
  def shortenedTitle(data)
    if (data.shortenedTitle != nil)
      then data.shortenedTitle
    else 
      data.title
    end
  end
end
```

edit2: 
Cleaner solution without a helper:

```
(current_page.data.shortenedTitle || current_page.data.title)
```